# How to go about writing a PKCS#11 Wrapper around my device?

Tags: security, pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I have made a very basic Soft-HSM - only for personal learning purposes. I want to add a PKCS#11 interface to it. Where can I learn about this, or perhaps find something open source already written for studying?

*I realize that this could be downvoted just for bringing this up (poor security, etc) but I wanted to ensure that its strictly for learning purposes.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to get familiar with PKCS#11 specificiation. I've created git repository [PKCS11-SPECS](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS) with all of its versions in one place. I personally consider PKCS#11 v2.20 to be the last "usable" version because in later versions authors removed important parts that are crucial to understand for anyone developing interoperable PKCS#11 libraries (session lifetime etc.). I warned them about removing those part but they didn't seem to care. So IMO PKCS#11 v2.20 is your best bet unless you need to use some other shiny fancy new algorithms that are not present in v2.20.

Another of my projects that you may find useful is [EMPTY-PKCS11](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/empty-pkcs11). It is minimalistic C library that implements PKCS#11 v2.20 API in the simplest possible way - all PKCS#11 functions except `C_GetFunctionList` function return `CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED` return value. It has been tested on several desktop and mobile platforms and as such can be used as a lightweight skeleton for the development of portable PKCS#11 libraries.

After that you can also take a look at [PKCS11-MOCK](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/pkcs11-mock) which is another minimalistic PKCS#11 v2.20 library. It is not a real cryptographic module but just a dummy mock object designed specifically for unit testing of some of my other projects.

I hope these projects could be a solid solid starting point in your learning process.